# how to give permission to WAS for writing file

Tags: file-io, websphere

i having task to upload file to Web application server, when test with local server its working fine, but once deploy into real server, when upload there is error 'Permission denied', do I have set any setting for writing permission,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple, just add `was.Policy` file with content

```
grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Into the `META-INF`, folder

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory read/write permissions for the user that the Web server is running under.

In Windows Server this is under [directory]>properties>security.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a file in the File System.

The file system has access restrictions.

These are typically controlled via the Java 2 Security.

Here is what i would do:

**Step 1:**

Turn off Java 2 Security and try the upload again. This should be successful.

**Step 2:**

Turn on Java 2 Security and give access to all users by tweaking Java 2 security policy file

**Step 3**

Change the security policy and provide the required access to relevent users only.

HTH

Manglu